# Representation of Weyl algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory

Let's consider an algebra $W$, generated by a family of differential operators of type $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_{k}(x) \cdot \frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}}$$ 
(may also known as Weyl algebra).

I would like to prove it does not admit a representation in $GL(H)$, $H$ is an arbitrary Hilbert space (in other words, there is no continous  $\varphi: W \rightarrow GL(H)$ such as $\varphi$ is a homomorphism).

Also, i can prove the following lemma which is thought to be helpful:

> Lemma
>   If $A$ is a unital Banach algebra, then there is no $a, b \in A$ such that $[a, b] = ab-ba=1$

(Skecth of the proof: assume that there exist such $x,y$, then by induction we get $xy^{n-1}-y^{n-1}x = ny^{n-1}$. $n||y^{n}|| = ||xy^{n-1}-y^{n-1}x|| \leq ||xy^{n-1}|| + ||y^{n-1}x|| \leq 2||x||||y^{n-11}$. Thus we get that $2||x||||y|| \geq n$ for any integer $n>0$, which is a contradiction.)

Is it possible to apply the lemma in order to obtain the desired result?

Any sort of help would be much appreciated.